# powershell azure device disable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this script:

```
Connect-msolservice -Credential $mycreds
Disable-MsolDevice -DeviceId device id here -Force
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Disable-MsolDevice : Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientFormat.set_LoadServiceModel(System.Func`1<Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel>)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Disable-MsolDevice -DeviceId device idh ere -Fo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Disable-MsolDevice], MissingMethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMethodException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.DisableDevice
```

does someone know what this error is?

It works on my main pc just not on the server so probably it is missing a module or something but what.